# Looking for complementary word related to "xenophobia'

Tags: cross-linguistic, sociolinguistics

The Greek-rooted word "xenophobia" is commonly used to refer to *"unjustified fear of an 'other'"* in English.

I'm looking some words which have related but different meanings:

*"unjustified loathing of family/clan/self"*

*"unjustified and possibly uncontrollable attraction to the 'alien' or 'other'"*

*"unjustified attraction to family/clan/self."*

I have no background in linguistics, and hope that someone out there may take pity on me and point me in the right direction.   Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antonym for *-phobia* "fear" - in modern English, at least - is usually *-philia* "love." So for your second definition you'd probably want [xenophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenophilia), though [allophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophilia) (*allos* "other") would also work.

For "family/clan" the Greek is *oikos*, yielding *oikophobia* and *oikophilia* respectively. The [first of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikophobia) has been used by some contemporary authors.